# Does nvd3 support IE9?

Tags: nvd3.js

d3 [supports IE9+](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#browser--platform-support), but nvd3 states it [supports IE10+](https://github.com/novus/nvd3#supported-browsers), yet I can find nothing in the commit logs stating a drop of IE9.  In fact, a [recent commit log](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/7d7cdeb3ee7c8213c510dbd06253a0fcaf82fc37) states a fix for IE9.

So, what's the status of IE9 support?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Social Compare](http://socialcompare.com/en/review/nvd3-javascript-graphic-charts) IE9 supports nvd3 only with [aight](https://github.com/shawnbot/aight). And if you can use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvd3#supported-browsers) it supports IE9.